# docker cannot be mounted correctly

Tags: docker

I'm learning docker and doing some exercises.

```bash
winpty docker run  -v $(pwd):/app alpine ls
```

I want to mount the current directory to app directory.
then i get the echo

```bash
\Git\app
bin
dev
...
```

I want to get

```
app
bin
dev
...
```

I'd like to ask what is the [\Git\app] and how can i fix it.

expectations the `ls` echo

```
app
bin
dev
...
```

actual  the `ls` echo

```
\Git\app
bin
dev
...
```

I try to use PowerShell

```bash
docker run -v ${PWD}:/app alpine ls
```

it works

```bash
app
bin
dev
```

I think it's git-bash that's not parsing the directories correctly

Comment: With a mount, this is not possible. A mount mounts the file system "as-is", there is no way to "restructure" the content of the mount.

Comment: it seems that winpty replaces `/app` with something else. check the output of `winpty echo /app`

Comment: I have install oh-my-zsh. it works too.
so I think the problem lies in the git-bash.